# Dialog datePicker bounds - Android

Tags: android

I'm using a datePicker dialog to pick the date, and I must set a lower and an upper bound. How can i do this?
Should I use the `public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)` method?

Please be explicit because I'm working with Android from 4 days only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose a DatePicker can NOT have a bound range. But you can check the date picked by user yourself. And if the date is invalid, you can alert the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `maxDate` and `minDate` like this:

```
Date upperLimit = new Date();
Date lowerLimit = new Date();

DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(getContext());

picker.setMaxDate(upperLimit.getTime());
picker.setMinDate(lowerLimit.getTime());
```

Cheers